# In Terraform, what is '${element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)}'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can anyone explain this line.

```
subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)}"
```

I used this in terraform code for creating one stack

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what the command does?

Answer (score 5):

`aws_subnet.public.*.id` return a list of subnet ids, e.g.:

```
["subnet-3232", "subnet-555", "subnet-6666"]
```

So `element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)` will pick a single subnet id from the list, depending on the value of `count.index`. For example:

```
element(["subnet-3232", "subnet-555", "subnet-6666"], 0) # pick first one
element(["subnet-3232", "subnet-555", "subnet-6666"], 1) # pick second one
element(["subnet-3232", "subnet-555", "subnet-6666"], 2) # pick last one
element(["subnet-3232", "subnet-555", "subnet-6666"], 3) # pick first one again (aka wrap-around)
```

Also if `count.index` is greater then the number of elements, it [element](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/element) will go back and start from the head of the list (aka  `"wrap-around"`).